# iOS: embeded Youtube video in Webview inside UITableViewCell not playing

Tags: ios, uitableview, webview, youtube

When my WebView is inside a normal UIView every thing works and video plays as expected. (I created a new sample project to test it.)

But when I put the WebView inside a UITableView. Its not playing. It loads the video player with video's thumbnail and big red play button. When I click play button, video won't play. The WebView goes black.

Here's my code

```
void LoadVideo (string videoId)
{
    nfloat width = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Size.Width - 32;
    nfloat height = VideoWebview.Frame.Size.Height;
    string embedHtml = "<iframe width=\"{0}\" height=\"{1}\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/{2}?modestbranding=1&showinfo=0\" frameborder=\"0\" style=\"margin:-8px;padding:0;\" allowfullscreen></iframe>";
    string html = string.Format (embedHtml, width, height, videoId);
    Console.WriteLine (html);
    VideoWebview.ScrollView.Bounces = false;
    VideoWebview.LoadHtmlString (html, new Foundation.NSUrl ("https://www.youtube.com"));
}
```

This works fine when the WebView is not inside a UITableViewCell. What am I doing wrong here? Any help is appreciated.

**Edit:**

I've found that it's some issue with my project. I created a new sample project and its working inside a UITableViewCell. But in the current project that I'm working it just don't work... not in UITableViewCell, not in UIView.

Comment: why you using embed code , you can directly use `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxxxx`

Comment: are you added the `NSAppTransportSecurity` in your .plist'